# sqlite-net - ordering by string Case Insensitive Accent Insensitive

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

How can I sort by a varchar column case insensitively and diacritic insensitively.

For example, I would execute the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY name ASC
```

And the result is:

- Alice
- Bob
- Cole
- Dale
- avril
- carl
- Átila

But I want it to be sorted like:

- Alice
- Átila
- avril
- Bob
- carl
- Cole
- Dale

Answer (score 2):

So there are two approaches for **case insensitive only** sorting:

1. Write a in-line sql with `ORDER BY` clause (obvious but *a bad practice*);

   ```
   SELECT name FROM user
   ORDER BY UPPER(name) ASC
   ```
2. Sort in memory, using C# with Linq would be something like this:

   ```
   connection.Table<User>()
       .OrderBy(user => user.Name, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
   ```

For diacritics insensitive sorting (aka Accent Insensitive) it would be only possible by removing the diacritics prior to inserting in db, or sorting in memory removing the diacritics on demand.